# How to extract text from image using pytesseract in colab?

Tags: python, ocr, google-colaboratory

I am getting this error when I try to use pytesseract in colab.

I am not sure how to fix this problem. I also install with **pip install tesseract**. But it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Or do you have any other python library OCR?

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TesseractNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    257         if e.errno != ENOENT:
    258             raise e
--> 259         raise TesseractNotFoundError()
    260 
    261     with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

Here is my code. I am trying to detect the number.

```
import pytesseract
roi = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(roi, lang='eng')
```

Comment: Can you please include the code that you are running, in the question

Comment: Hi @KnowledgeGainer, I just upload it can you check it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work in **colab** in-case pytesseract is not installed.

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
!pip install pytesseract
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/path'))
print(text)
```